# How to put RTMP stream into in node.js wrtc

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mediastream

I am creating a server that receives an RTMP stream and sends it to a WebRTC peer. CAM -> RTMP -> RTMP Server -> RTMP stream To peer (node.js) I don't know how to move RTMP into webrtc stream.

Here's how to load a cam image on webrtc from a local browser.

```
let localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(CONSTRAINTS);
this.video.srcObject = localStream;
localStream.getTracks().forEach(
    track => this.rtc.addTrack(track, localStream)
);
```

But how do I put rtmp stream to a peer on a node.js server?

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to depacket the video received via RTMP followed by packeting to WebRTC.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: You can check here: https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/blob/master/src/main/java/io/antmedia/webrtc/adaptor/RTMPAdaptor.java